# Why does environment variable get deleted after the end of a python script?

Tags: python

While running a python program I set the following environment variable:

```
import os
os.environ['access_token'] = 'dc432423fsddgg'
```

After running the above script and then when I run a different script:

```
import os    
print(os.environ.get('access_token))
```

I get the output as `None`. How can I store the environment variable 'access_token' permanently? Is there any other efficient way to store sensitive information such as access tokens?

Comment: Environment variables are local to a process.  They are inherited by child processes at the time the processes are created, but any changes are not reflected in any existing processes other than the one in which the change is made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environments are not global. You are only setting `access_token` in the environment of the process executing your first script. That environment is discarded when that process ends.

If you want to communicate between two separate processes whose lifetimes do not overlap, you need to use the file system or a 3rd process that continues running in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wouldn't it be insecure storing it in a file?

Comment: Sure. Environments aren't typically any more secure, though. (For example, if you have a `/proc` file system and want to see the environment of process `1234`, you can just read `/proc/1234/environ`.)